# Native interface for IOS is OK, how do I handle Android functionality?

Tags: codenameone

For IOS I have a native interface function and it works well.
For Android I may use the standard codenameone function.
How do I handle the Android function?
I saw, using `Display.getInstance().getPlatformName()` is not a good idea
to change functions between IOS and Android!
Also in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to check the platform name.

Return `false` for `isSupported()` in your Android native implementation code. After that, in your callback class check if `isSupported()` is true, if not, then check if the platform is Android.

```
MyNative native = NativeLookup.create(MyNative.class);
if(native != null && native.isSupported()) {
    //call your native interface method here
} else if("and".equalsIgnoreCase(CN.getPlatformName())) {
    //call Codename One method here for android
} else {
    //perform any default action here for other platforms
}
```